# Using cite tags on content that has embedded cites (nested cites)

Tags: html, citations

I was reading about using the html `cite` tag recently and I read something about that when you quote something that itself has a `cite` inside of it, you should add an extra attribute to all `cite` tags inside to state they are from the content and not the author for what you are quoting.

I just can't seem to find the page anymore where I read it, so was wondering if anyone could help me out here with the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) in the W3C HTML5 spec, buried amid the numerous examples:

> **Note:** There is no formal method for indicating the markup in a `blockquote` is from a quoted source. It is suggested that if the `footer` or `cite` elements are included and these elements are also being used within a `blockquote` to identify citations, the elements from the quoted source could be annotated with metadata to identify their origin, for example by using the `class` attribute (a defined extensibility mechanism).
>
> **Code Example:**
>
> In this example the source of a quote includes a `cite` element, which is annotated using the `class` attribute:
>
> ```
>   <blockquote>
>   <p>My favorite book is <cite class="from-source">At Swim-Two-Birds</cite></p>
>   <footer>- <cite>Mike[tm]Smith</cite></footer>
>   </blockquote>
> ```

There is no particular right or wrong syntax *per se*, but the spec suggests using the `class` attribute for this purpose.

Interestingly, WHATWG HTML does not mention this at all, presumably because it has a different set of rules on how to provide attribution/citations for a `blockquote` element — namely, attribution may never appear *inside* it, which precludes using a `cite` element within it to provide attribution, thereby eliminating the ambiguity presented by W3C HTML5.